# WinSock2 C++ - Multiple sockets stored as one

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock2

When I was first learning about using Sockets in c++, I found a very informative video that I cannot seem to find anymore. It was probably removed, but that's not the point. In the video the person making the video somehow (on the server app) had three SOCKET variables, one I don't remember what did, one for individual clients, and one for all clients, almost like an array.

I have decided to try to learn about sockets again, I have a very simple IM between the server and a client, multiple clients can connect but clients cannot communicate with each other, so what I need to do is to make a socket array, like explained above, but the problem is that I don't remember how to do it, or how to add a single connection to it.

If anyone knows of any other way to do it I am open for solutions. The code is very simple main thread to recv() messages, other thread to send(). Same for client.

Thank you to anyone who replies.

Comment: How to handle multiple clients is a broad topic. Google will give you plenty of approaches.

Comment: @deviantfan Thank you for replying. I know it is a very broad topic; however, I did give a specific example unless someone knew a better (safer, easier, better in anyway) way to do it. I have googled it, and anything I found was too difficult to follow, or only covered Server to Client IM. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bit hard to answer in general, but if I understood you right you want a list of all opened sockets that you would like to use later to distribute a message.

At some point in your code you must have something like:

```
new_socket = accept(...);
```

Make a globally available array of SOCKET variables and add `new_socket` into it whenever you establish a connection.

If you use C++ use STL containers. Include `#include <list>` and as a global variable define:

```
std::list<SOCKET> Connections;
```

Than whenever receiving a new connection do:

```
new_socket = accept(...);
Connections.push_back(new_sockets);
```

When you want to use to send to all of them do:

```
for(std::list<SOCKET>::iterator i=Connections.begin(); i!=Connections.end(); i++)
   ... use (*i) as a socket
```

And when connections are closed simply remove them from the vector:

```
Connections.remove(old_socket);
```

As discussed in comments, you can do it with simple array like `SOCKET Connections[20]`, but than you have to deal with manipulating the array by hand when inserting and removing element. All that is already done in std::list. No use to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Okay, yes you are correct in what I want, a list of all open sockets. so, I think we're on the right track, I wasn't sure if there was such thing as an array of socket vars. If I'm understanding your answer correctly, I can do this to define my socket array: SOCKET Connections[20];        From there the only problem would be how do I actually add new_socket to Connections. I already have new_socket to be accepted.

Comment: You simply say `Connections[5]=new_socket;`. This is the easy part. The trick is that you will have to deal with connections disappearing, thus you must remove the corresponding values from your `Connections`.

Comment: Okay, so we know how to add them, but how do I remove them. I can keep a variable, such as `Count` and add 1 to it for every connection and remove `Connections[Count]`, the question is how do I clear the slot?

Comment: @Reborn Just shift all the connections after it down a slot and decrement the number of slots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a list which will store Socket FD(file descriptor). FDs are integer number, unique for every socket. As you have commented you know how to add them.

To, remove them you will call close() socket API to close the socket first. You will know about closing socket using FD in [this](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_13.html#SEC237) link. After closing the socket successfully just remove the index which consists the FD of the socket which has been closed. If you have any further query you can ask.